# Using Ajax to pass PHP var

Tags: php, ajax

There is ajax script

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // add click event to link
    $("#refresh").click(function() {
    // pass the value of the new password
      $("#Container").load("10digpassgen.php");
      return false;
    });
  });
 </script>
```

How Can I put output from #Container to php variable?
I want this generated password put into database ( I know how to do it ).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: If you want to pass data to a php file you need Ajax according to your code

Comment: @SilvioCro php script generated for me random password. I want to store this password to put it into my db

Answer (score 0):

You can store return output in the hidden field and when the form submit you can get that value in the post or get.